# C++ Código de Fibonacci que imprima la serie desde la función recursiva

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión, fibonacci

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n){

    if(n < 2)
        return n;

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
  }
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;


  fib(n);
  for(int i =0; i <= n; i++)
    cout << fib(i) << " ";


  return 0;
}
```

Tengo que hacer un programa que imprima la serie de fibonacci usando una función recursiva, pero en la función main solo puedo llamar a la función. Eso quiere decir que tengo que imprimir la serie desde la función recursiva. No puedo llamar cout << desde la función main. Por lo tanto, el código de arriba no me lo toman por válido.
Si el input es 5 el resultado debe ser: 1 1 2 3 4
Si el input es 8: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?¿Donde esta el error? No vale solo con poner código. Si no nos explicas lo que necesitas no sabremos ayudarte. Echale un vistazo a [ask]

Comment: Realiza la pregunta, ahi simplemente has puesto un trozo de codigo. Explica el codigo y tu pregunta.

Comment: Te falta un caso base para solucionar esa recursión infinita que tienes. 
(Cúrrate más la pregunta y te ayudaremos más)

Answer (score 3):

Si la función tiene que, por un lado calcular la sucesión y por otro imprimirla entonces la función necesita dos variables:

1. El valor de la sucesión a calcular (no merece más explicaciones)
2. Un booleano que indique si debe imprimir o no el resultado de la sucesión

Algo así:

```
int fib(int n, bool print = true)
{
  int toReturn = 0;

  if( n > 0 )
  {
    if( n < 2 )
      toReturn = 1;
    else
     toReturn = fib(n-1,false) + fib(n-2,false);

    if( print )
    {
      fib(n-1);
      std::cout << toReturn << ' ';
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}

int main() {
  fib(5); std::cout << '\n';
  fib(8); std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Los saltos de línea en el main los he puesto para separar ambas secuencias.

Comment: ¡Eres un ángel, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas buscando es esto:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x == 1)
        return 1;

    return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);
}

int main() {
    cout << fib(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no intentes usar snippets de js o html para código c++

Comment: ¿Seguro que busca eso? Yo no veo "*que imprima la serie desde la función recursiva*" O_o

Comment: Donde lo imprima creo que es lo de menos el probema era que su algoritmo estaba equivocado. Lo de usar snippets es mas que nada porque me resulta mucho mas comodo copiar ahi el código pero lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster claro, es complicado de decir cuando el OP  no ha hecho ninguna pregunta XD

Comment: Pero ten en cuenta que aunque el algoritmo sea incorrecto puede no ser la duda del OP... puede haberse equivocado al copiar el ejemplo. Deberías esperarte a que el OP exponga su duda concreta

Comment: @solamente "es lo menos del problema" es algo que no sabemos, pues en realidad no sabemos cuál considera el preguntante que es problema principal.

Comment: @solamente  pregunta editada!

Comment: @eferion el problema es poder imprimir la serie desde de la función donde se lleva a cabo el algoritmo.

Comment: @Isaii'catmat lo se, he visto la edición de tu pregunta... el comentario al que te refieres no iba dirigido a tí sino al autor de la respuesta. No tiene sentido responder a una pregunta cuando no se sabe qué se está preguntando... porque lo más probable es que la respuesta acabe siendo errónea (como efectivamente así ha sido en este caso)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Pregunta editada! Lo siento, no pensé que responderían tan rápido y varias personas, así que solo lancé el código a medias y sin pregunta.